# Link between MS Access application and C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I've a Winforms C# application from which I'd like to be able to connect to an Access 2007 application. Basically, users click a button in the winforms app, and they're taken to a specific form within a MS access application they have running.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but why not rewrite the Access application with WinForms?

Comment: The access application is a big, legacy app used throughout the firm to do their daily work. The winforms app is, in fact, a replacement for the Acess app, but for only a small part of it. Users need to be able to link back from the new app to the existing.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using DDE, consider automation.  You'll need to add a reference the relevant PIA libraries, and then you can have code somewhat more familiar to an Access developer, like this:

```
var access = new Access.Application();
access.OpenCurrentDatabase("MyDB.accdb");
access.OpenForm("frmNavigate");
```

Comment: I have found that using automation always starts a new instance of Access. DDE will locate an already running instance.

Comment: @user957902 you can grab an existing instance with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject` (though this approach also has problems).  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126 for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You will have to use DDE. Ugly old technology but it is still in Access 2007. I am using the [NDde](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) library on codeplex.

```
using (DdeClient client = new DdeClient("MSACCESS", "MyDB.accdb"))
{
           String DdeCommand =
            "[OpenForm frmNavigate,,,,,,UserOpenArgs]";
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            client.Execute(DdeCommand, 5000);
        }
        catch (NDde.DdeException ex)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Logger.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I'll check NDde out.  To be clear, the Access application is access forms connected to a MS SQL database. There isn't an .accdb file...Does that change anything?

Comment: You have to have an accdb or accde file that your Access forms are in right ? We used SQLServer linked tables and have an accdb file for development and then convert it into accde file for deployment. This will work with either.

Comment: user957902: I have an adp file, that's it.

Comment: I think the adp file will work, as that appears to be where the forms are stored. If you doble clink on the adp file, does that start the access application ?

Comment: Then you should be able to use MyApp.adp instead of MyApp.accdb in the example above.